# ImportError: No module named caffe while running spark-submit

Tags: python, ubuntu, apache-spark, caffe, pycaffe

While running a `spark-submit` on a spark standalone cluster comprised of one master and 1 worker, the `caffe` python module does not get imported due to error `ImportError: No module named caffe`

This doesn't seem to be an issue whenever I run a job locally by 
`spark-submit --master local script.py` the `caffe` module gets imported just fine.

The environmental variables are currently set under `~/.profile` for spark and caffe and they are pointing to the `PYTHONPATH`.

Is `~/.profile` the correct location to set these variables or perhaps a system wide configuration is needed such as adding the variables under `/etc/profile.d/`

Comment: please check if this is useful https://github.com/yahoo/CaffeOnSpark/wiki/GetStarted_standalone

Comment: Thanks Arunakiran, that example is using CaffeOnSpark a Yahoo open platform that I believe uses Scala instead of python. We have looked at that but it doesn't benefit us at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the CaffeOnSpark team ported Caffe to a distributed environment backed by Hadoop and Spark. You cannot, I am 99.99% sure, use Caffe alone *(without any modifications)* in a Spark cluster or any distributed environment per se. (Caffe team is known to be working on this).

If you need distributed deep-learning using Caffe, please follow the building method mentioned here in https://github.com/yahoo/CaffeOnSpark/wiki/build to build CaffeOnSpark for that and use CaffeOnSpark instead of Caffe.

But, best bet will be to follow either this [GetStarted_standalone wiki](https://github.com/yahoo/CaffeOnSpark/wiki/GetStarted_standalone) or [GetStarted_yarn wiki](https://github.com/yahoo/CaffeOnSpark/wiki/GetStarted_yarn) to create you a distributed environment to carry out deep-learning.

Further, to add python, please go through [GetStarted_python wiki](https://github.com/yahoo/CaffeOnSpark/wiki/GetStarted_python).

Also, since you mentioned that you are using Ubuntu [here](https://github.com/yahoo/CaffeOnSpark/issues/164), please use `~/.bashrc` to update environment your variables. You will have to source the file after the changes: `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks Arun, this is exactly what I needed to know.